# Image background cut off in Firefox only

Tags: html, css, firefox

I use images as buttons, and have some CSS to make the background look and behave like a button. This works perfectly in all browsers normally, and on most of the pages I have. On this one button in Firefox only, half of the image is cut off.

1. How can I get it to appear the same in Firefox?

http://jsfiddle.net/863ux696/ View this in Chrome and then Firefox to see what I mean.

[image: Correct view, Chrome] <-Correct view, Chrome
[image: Incorrect view, Firefox] <- Incorrect view, Firefox

CSS:

```
.login-button {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;

    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/274x59);
    width: 274px;
    padding-left: 274px;
    height: 59px;
}
```

HTML

```
<img class="login-button" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the img as a a `block` or `inline-block` element.

```
.login-button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/863ux696/1/

Comment: That did it, thanks. Any idea why other identical buttons wouldn't behave like this? Or why Firefox wouldn't place nicely with the existing CSS?

Comment: I don't think Firefox does it so wrongly, like a, span, img is an inline element, but it's different from them. but in your example it is the same. see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/863ux696/2/ try toggling the inline-block on the span tag.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `<img>` tag with a `<div>` one :

```
<div class="login-button"></div>
```

You are using an `<img>` tag, but you are in fact not really displaying an image. I understand that you probably choosed this one because you have an image in the background.

Using `<img class="login-button" />` is a bit heretic, as you do not have an `src` attribute, and this is against the specification of `<img>` tag

[Demo of the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/863ux696/3/)